# A vector Jacobi identity

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $\mathbf{A}$, $\mathbf{B}$, $\mathbf{C}$ be three solenoidal vector fields i.e. $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{A}=\nabla\cdot\mathbf{B}=\nabla\cdot\mathbf{C}=0$.

Can we prove that 
$\mathbf{A}\times\nabla\times(\mathbf{B}\times\mathbf{C})+\mathbf{C}\times\nabla\times(\mathbf{A}\times\mathbf{B})+\mathbf{B}\times\nabla\times(\mathbf{C}\times\mathbf{A})=0$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the identity is true. A counterexample:
$$\mathbf{A}=(-x,y,0),\;\;
\mathbf{B}=(0,1,0),\;\;
\mathbf{C}=(0,0,1).$$
All three divergences vanish while
$$\mathbf{A}\times\nabla\times(\mathbf{B}\times\mathbf{C})+\mathbf{C}\times\nabla\times(\mathbf{A}\times\mathbf{B})+\mathbf{B}\times\nabla\times(\mathbf{C}\times\mathbf{A})=(-1,0,0)$$
does not vanish.